# Why did GNU's expand convert a tab to less than 8 columns?

Tags: coreutils

Using `expand`, I don't understand how many spaces it converts tabs to. From `info expand`:

> By default, expand converts all tabs to spaces. It preserves backspace
>   characters in the output; they decrement the column count for tab
>   calculations. The default action is equivalent to -t 8 (set tabs every
>   8 columns).

And yet:

```
$ cat file
aa  bb
$ cat -A file
aa^Ibb$
$ wc -m file
6 file
$ expand file > file2
$ cat -A file2
aa      bb$
$ wc -m file2
11 file2
```

Here it converted tab to 6 columns. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [OpenGroup description of `expand`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expand.html):

> The *expand* utility shall write files or the standard input to the standard output with `<tab>` characters replaced with one or more `<space>` characters needed to pad to the next tab stop.

`-t 8` puts the tab *stops* 8 characters apart.  As the input had two other characters (`aa`) at the start of the line before the tab character, only six spaces are needed to reach the next tab stop.

Comment: That explains a lot, I didn't know what a tab stop is. Thanks.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/711019/38062 might help in that regard.